# Why does my AWS account was not granted SageMaker default limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The *AWS Service limits* page on the AWS documentation states that default limit for most of the SageMaker notebook instances is 20. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqPnW.png)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

But I’m not able to start any notebook instance other than ml.t2.medium, otherwise I get a ResourceLimitExceeded saying that my current instance limit for this type is 0. I know how to request a limit increase, but I’ll have to make a request for each individual instance type which really annoys me. I was wondering why do I not have the default limits.

Comment: That sounds like the free tier. Make sure you have a valid payment method on your AWS account if you want to exceed the free tier.

Comment: That what I thought first but my credit card is linked to my account and I have a 150$ credit balance (via AWS Educate program).

Comment: You probably do need to contact Amazon, then.

Comment: Is this an AWS Educate *"starter"* account?  Those accounts don't appear to support t2 machines larger than t2.small.  https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf